# using value on select box as a input to save into sql table

Tags: php, mysql

here the scene. This code below is for me to retrieve the data from table "koti_images" and display at the page in a form of select box which is already success.

so the question is, it is possible to make sure when user select the value from the select box which is in this case is the "plan" and click save, that data will be saved in other table in mysql. I already create new table "koti_imagedigital" but i dont have idea on how to pass the value that were selected into this table. i am new into this stuff, so hope you all can help me. Thank You.

```
<form name="form_update" method="post" action="testkoti.php">
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","koti");
    //============== check connection
    if(mysqli_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    //=============================
    //This creates the drop down box
    echo "<select name= 'plan_id'>";
    echo '<option value="">'.'--- Please Select Plan ---'.'</option>';


    $query_display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM koti_images");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_display))
    {
        echo "<option value='". $row['file_name']."'>".$row['file_name']
     .'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';
    ?>
           <div class="box-footer">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</a>
               <button href = "#" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save & Exit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: and what is the status of this question? there's an answer below, but not accepted nor commented on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this to get the value and then proceed to insert the value to the database. Remember to sanitize the value if you ever want to output it. And use prepared statements and bound parameters when inserting to the database.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['plan_id'])) {

        $var = $_POST['plan_id'];

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // prepare and bind
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO your_table (row) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $var);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        echo "Saved.";

    }

?>

<form name="form_update" method="post" action="testkoti.php">
    <select name="plan_id">
        <option value="first">First</option>
        <option value="second">Second</option>
        <option value="third">Third</option>
    </select>
</form>
```